# delete database and configure database options in DBCA greyed out (disabled)

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, linux

I am using oracle 11g R2 on `Linux Redhat 6.3` and  created a lot of databases. At that time there was no problem. But currently I am seeing that in `DBCA` (Database Configuration Assistant) application some options are disabled as follows:-

1 Create  a Database - ENABLED

2 Configure Database Options - DISABLED

3 Delete a Database  - DISABLED

4 Manage Templates - ENABLED

I don't understand why this happening but in starting all the options were enabled.

**EDIT :**

`oratab` file content, inside `etc/oratab`

**

```
# This file is used by ORACLE utilities.  It is created by root.sh
# and updated by the Database Configuration Assistant when creating
# a database.
# A colon, ':', is used as the field terminator.  A new line terminates
# the entry.  Lines beginning with a pound sign, '#', are comments.
#
# Entries are of the form:
#   $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y>:
#
# The first and second fields are the system identifier and home
# directory of the database respectively.  The third filed indicates
# to the dbstart utility that the database should , "Y", or should not,
# "N", be brought up at system boot time.
#
# Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.
#
#
Dev:/oracle11gr2/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:N
Stage:/oracle11gr2/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:N
Test:/oracle11gr2/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:N
qa1:/oracle11gr2/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:N
Dev2:/oracle11gr2/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:N
Qual:/oracle11gr2/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:N
fStage:/oracle11gr2/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:N
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer after long investigation, the problem in my case is `root.sh` under `$ORACLE_HOME/root.sh` is not running fine, so in-order to fix this issue I need to use root user then navigate to `$ORACLE_HOME` and execute the script. it will ask you to `Enter the full pathname of the local bin directory: [/usr/local/bin]` enter the correct values and replace the old ones. after that open new terminal and use `dbca` everything will work fine.

Note in-order to get everything back to Normal state I copied everything inside the old `oratab` into the new one.

Answer (score 1):

DBCA relies on `/etc/oratab`. If that file is empty, or the entry for the database you want to delete is missing, the option(s) will be disabled.

Comment: I checked the oratab and posted its content in the edit section.